# Pass events to youtube iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, youtube

I try to create a transparent block on top of youtube iframe video to get some statistics. For example, user clicks somewhere on player to play or pause videos, div receives mouse `click` event, saves info somewhere and pass event to the youtube iframe to play this video. How can i do that? `trigger` function doesn't work for some reason.
Here's how my code looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#hideme{
    background: #000;
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.0;
}
iframe{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 350px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<iframe width="853" height="480" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/9bZkp7q19f0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<div id="hideme"></div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('iframe').load(function(){
        var iframe = $(this);

        var hideme = $('#hideme');
        hideme.width(iframe.width());
        hideme.height(iframe.height());
        hideme.css('left', iframe.position().left);
        hideme.css('top', iframe.position().top);

        hideme.on("click", function(event){
            iframe.trigger(event);
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kv8dQ/. By the way, can't figure out why but in fiddle div is not on top of iframe. On my localhost works fine though.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Comment: Thanks, but what if I don't want to use API? For some embed players (not youtube, others) there's no API to use.

Comment: Not sure, I've never attempted what you're trying. Sorry!

Comment: Have you ever made it work ? I'm trying to do the same thing, for some of the YouTube fucntions